# Typecast error of postgres in Jboss while calling finder method in Ejb 2.1

Tags: java, postgresql, jdeveloper, jboss6.x, ejb-2.x

First of all, things were working perfectly in my previous laptop, when I shifted my code to the new laptop I am getting this error, Basically, I am calling finder method in my EJB and code of it was working fine as in EJB-jar it looks like this

```
  <query>
    <query-method>
      <method-name>finduserrightsonform</method-name>
      <method-params>
        <method-param>java.lang.String</method-param>
        <method-param>java.lang.String</method-param>
      </method-params>
    </query-method>
    <ejb-ql>select object(o) from UserRightsOnForm o where o.ser_groups_users_id=?1 and o.ser_form_id=?2</ejb-ql>
  </query>
```

as both columns in DB are integers so as in my previous laptop Postgres auto-cast it's there, but what I am missing is strange.

so far as I tried

1. cast using cast(columnname as character varying) e.g. it also
   through error
2. change method param to Integer it will not work as well, in fact,
   stoped deployed the jar
3. changing the Postgress versions to the previous one.
4. casting like using ::smallint

**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying
ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 3)   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.**

its look like the environment maybe jar issue but what I am missing not catching it.

calling code:

```
sms.viewUserRightsOnFormImpl(userId, "validationForm", groupId);
```

defination:

```
Collection findUserRightOnForm(String user_id, String form_id) throws FinderException;
```

using 
Jdevelper 11g
postgress 9.2
Jboss 6
EJB 2.1

Note: Tried all google links and stackover links almost wasted my 2 days.

Comment: Apparently `ser_groups_users_id` and `ser_form_id` are integers, so why do you pass a String string value as the parameter? Why don't you pass integers to your method and thus to the SQL query?

Comment: basically ejb 2.1 is supporting it and it works like that and all things are working fine in another laptop, i tried that way as well but its not working.

Comment: Comparing a string to an integer is plain wrong. Would you expect `"42".equals(42)` to return `true` in Java? `42.equals("42")` wouldn't even compile (which is what you try to do) . I still don't understand why you can't just change your method parameters to the correct type. Even if it does (sometimes) work, it will lead to queries that might not use an index due to the evil implicit type casting

Comment: okey as i told you its not working as well, i created same method with both integer type but now its even not letting me deploy and throwing this error
.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException:Error compiling EJB-QL statement for EJB 'SysmgrUserRightsOnForm': select object(o) from SysmgrUserRightsOnForm o where o.ser_user_id=1 and o.ser_form_id=2
at org.jboss.as.cmp.jdbc.JDBCEJBQLQuery.<init>(JDBCEJBQLQuery.java:58)
at org.jboss.as.cmp.jdbc.JDBCCommandFactory.createEJBQLQuery(JDBCCommandFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.as.cmp.jdbc.JDBCQueryManager.start(JDBCQueryManager.java:223)
at

Comment: org.jboss.as.cmp.jdbc.JDBCStoreManager.startStoreManager(JDBCStoreManager.java:240)
at org.jboss.as.cmp.jdbc.JdbcStoreManagerStartService.start(JdbcStoreManagerStartService.java:44)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.cmp.ejbql.ParseException: Encountered " <INTEGER_LITERAL> "1 "" at line 1, column 68.
Was expecting one of:
"CONCAT"
"SUBSTRING"
"("
<STRING_LITERAL>
STRING_VALUED_PARAMETER"
"STRING_VALUED_PATH"

Comment: above two messages are one error against your way now its not deploying, by string parameter atleast they worked and deploy easily on other pc

Comment: Its not that simple as it looks :) never seen sucha a issue in my 4 year programing life

Comment: ?? you there ??